# having problem installing libmysqlc++-dev

Tags: mysql

```
aanchal@aanchal-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlc++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysqlc++-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmysqlc++-dev'
```

'universe'options is enabled in the software center.

well thanks everyone i typed the command wrong.it was installed successfully. and i tried running the program test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
using namespace std;
MYSQL *connection, mysql;
MYSQL_RES *result;
MYSQL_ROW row;
int query_state;
int main() {
return 0;
}
```

using the command:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -L/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -I/usr/include/mysql
```

it didnt give me any error message. so does that mean everything's working fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an unwanted `c` in `libmysqlc++-dev`. It should be `libmysql++-dev`.

```
sudo aptitude show libmysql++-dev 
Package: libmysql++-dev                  
State: not installed
Version: 3.2.1+pristine-1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/libdevel
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Uncompressed Size: 2,350 k
Depends: libmysql++3 (= 3.2.1+pristine-1), libmysqlclient-dev
Suggests: libmysql++-doc
Description: MySQL C++ library bindings (development)
 MySQL++ is a complex C++ API for MySQL (and other SQL databases soon). The goal of this API is to make working with Queries as easy as
 working with other STL containers.
```

Install `libmysql++-dev` with

> `sudo apt-get install libmysql++-dev`

Answer (score 4):

There is no package named `libmysqlc++-dev` in Ubuntu.

If you want the development files for the MySQL C++ library bindings install the package `libmysql++-dev` (without the `c`).

Answer (score 0):

The package is `libmysql++-dev`, without the `c`.

If you get the same error when installing the above, then you'll need to change your archive mirror:

- Select one from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), making sure it's close to your location.
- Enter `gksudo gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list` into the terminal
- Replace the current mirror with your newly-chosen one

The package should then install with no problems.